# Regularization Coefficient in Polynomial Regression

Tags: machine-learning, non-linear-regression

[Regularization Term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XO3x.png)

Overfitting in Polynomial Regression, Comparing the training set's root mean squared error and the validation set's root-mean-squared-error.

[Graph of the root-mean-square-error vs lnλ for the M=9 polynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8GF9.png)

I didn't understand this graph properly. While training the model to learn the parameters, we have to set λ = 0 since it doesn't make sense to already select the value of λ and then proceed with the training. **So How is the training error varying as we vary the value of λ**?. We divided the dataset into the valid and the train so that we train the model in the training set, and then verify the validation through the valid set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may confuse concepts here.

***Why the loss function?***

You apply a shrinkage penalty to your loss function.
This will nudge your model towards finding weights closer to zero. Which can e.g. be helpful to do regularization by trading variance with bias (see e.g. the Ridge Regression in  *“An Introduction to Statistical Learning”* by Witten et al.)

**How to train?**

Setting the term λ after training should not affect your trained model. Think about it in terms of linear regression: as soon as you have fitted the linear regression function, your error function does not matter anymore. You just apply the linear regression function.

Thus, you have to set the λ parameter during training.
Otherwise, your model will optimize the parameters without the regularization term and will thus not shrink the sum of weights. Hence, you are actually training your model without regularization.

**How to find a good value for λ?**

You have to distinguish multiple steps:

*Training*: You train a model setting λ to a fixed value on your training data. The λ does not change during training but must not be zero ( if you want to have regularization).

This training will yield a model; let’s call it Model λ1.

*Single Validation Run*: You validate how well Model λ1 performs on the validation set. This tells you how and if λ improved your model, but not if there is a better λ.

*Cross-Validation Idea*: Train multiple models and use validation runs to evaluate their performance to find the best λ. In other words, you train multiple models (e.g. Model λ2 .. λ10) with different λ values. Then you can compare their validation set performance among each other, to see which value for λ is best (on the validation set).

*Why having a 3 set split ( train / validation / test)*: If you pick a final model with this procedure (e.g. Model λ3) you still don’t know how well your model generalizes because you have been using the validation set to find a good value for λ. Thus, you would expect your model to perform rather well on the validation set.

Hence, you evaluate your final model on the test set which your model has never seen, and where you never performed any kind of parameter optimization. The performance you measure is the final performance of your model. It is important that you do not evaluate multiple models on the training set, and then select the best because, then, again you would be optimizing the performance on the training set.

**How to interpret the plot?**

This is actually hard without some more knowledge about the problem you are tackling.
On the first look, it seems like your model is overfitting for small values of λ and improves its performance on the validation set for larger values due to regularization.

Comment: > Thus, you have to set the λ parameter during training.
Then why do we need a validation set? Sorry If I'm still not getting this right, but if we are training λ in the training set, then there's no need for a proxy of the Training set such as validation set right? 

We verify the validity of the Model in the Validation set and train λ in the Validation set right?
As I understand, We train the model only once, and then experiment with different values of λ in the validation set until we find a good regularization coefficient. Hence my doubt why was the training set varying as we varied λ

Comment: I updated the answer with a more elaborated description. Hope that clarifies it a bit. I really recommend reading Witten et al. "introduction to statistical learning". It is so helpful to understand core concepts of ML.  It also includes many exercises to apply them correctly. Although it is about non-NN methods many ideas of the book transfer rather nicely to NNs. Furthermore, they are initially easier to grasp because you do not have the added complexity of NNs.

Comment: That Cleared up a lot of things for me, Thanks!!